# Looping through JSON file and inserting into mysql database table using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a number of values in a JSON file set out as follows:

```
[{"scraped_at": 1533384162.2934802, "server_id": "461235834994032661", "invite_code": "5uWt6B", "server_name": "Magic Pokemon", "members": ["115385224119975941", "133557837598031872"]}
```

As can be seen the last value is another array. I've been trying to use the following code to insert into the mysql database using node.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var obj;
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "root",
database: "list"
});

fs.readFile('list.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
obj = JSON.parse(data);
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        const s_at = obj[i].scraped_at;
        const s_id = obj[i].server_id;
        const s_inv = obj[i].invite_code;
        const s_sn = obj[i].server_name;
        const mbs = obj[i].members;

        const sql = 'INSERT INTO members (scraped_at, server_id, invite_code, server_name, servermbs) VALUES ('+s_at+','+s_id+','+s_inv+','+s_sn+','+mbs+')';

        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("x record inserted");
        });
    }
});
});
```

I'm currently getting the following error thrown:

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RP,115385224119975941,133557837598031872,160105994217586689,212681528730189824,2' at line 1

Anyone got any ideas what is up with it and if so any solutions?

Apologies if the code doesn't look too great as I've never been good at formatting on this community site.

Thanks!

Comment: Your error has 6 fields and your SQL for the insert has 5. Whatever `RP` is it needs to be quoted in SQL. Does jodejs provide something to prevent SQL injection? You should use it if it does.

Comment: @danblack Well the first line funnily has the part with the RP on it and it is within quotes as follows: `"Magik and Personality RP", "members":`

Comment: @danblack If you look at how the JSON is formatted there are only 5 fields but the `"members"` field is an array of members that belong to that particular server.

Comment: Look to using a [library](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) to prevent SQL injection. Is `Magik and Personality RP` still quoted in js (e.g. does the string begin with a quote)? Is servermbs a JSON type? You'll need to ensure that its a json object string when you insert it.

Comment: Can you echo/print the sql constant? If so, edit your question and show it. I suspect that in the values part of the insert, your values are not quoted.

Comment: Also, for each member id on each row, you'll need to loop through that array and create an insert for each member ID.

Comment: I'm really not sure if my question has been clouded here. I do even say in the original question that I'm looping through the JSON file in order to insert all of the records stored in the JSON file into a mysql database table.

Comment: This is being done on my localhost server and is not part of a proper application. When the whole lot has been exported into the mysql table that will be then taken and uploaded to the main server. The point of this question is to find out what is going wrong with the taking of the JSON data and inserting it into the mysql table?? NodeJS is capable of performing this operation, plain old PHP is not.

Comment: I will cover any security issues such as SQL injection etc.. once I build the main application and deploy it to the main hosting server.